# Django admin login csrf error only on https

Tags: python, django, nginx, cloudflare, django-csrf

My django application is working fine both on locally and on server with http. But when I am enabling https for my domain it stops working and giving me csrf error.

[image]

Once again. The problem is not happening on http. Only on https.

My django application is dockarized. Also I am using nginxproxymanager as an alternative to nginx. Because it gives an easy gui to manage sites and handle ssl. I am using cloudflare to manage my dns.

Here is my settings.py:

```py
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://api.mailgrass.com", "http://api.mailgrass.com"]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["https://api.mailgrass.com", "http://api.mailgrass.com"]
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
```

Please help me solve this issue. I am pulling my hair for the last couple of days.